# Unable to commit files

Tags: jenkins, maven-release-plugin

we are getting below error when we are performing maven release for the project[employee-model] in Jenkins tool.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project employee-model: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR] git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'jenkins@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.(none)')
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Reconciliation-release-employee-model/workspace/cm
```

Comment: Make sure that the "jenkins@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.(none)" is authorized to push. go to your GIT server and make sure you have such user defined, and with the right Read permissions to the repository. check the SSH keys if you're using ssh. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your problem is not Jenkins but git account. 
From the OS try first to run, as jenkins user ( assuming linux ):

```
cd .../path/to/project/
git push
```

You will have the same error message:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

issue the 'git config' commands as suggested and try to push again. if it fixed - it should be ok from Jenkins also.